# Rewrite URL containing ... in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sometimes I find that URLs on my website show up with `mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=`.

For example:

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php​?mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=6goevo28​vf18ubqgb5uh6r08b2&topic=332242​.msg916981

http://mywebsite.com/index.php​?mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=6gqvo88l​u5fnl1qmj7temt0113&topic=316196​.msg931242
```

The part that contains `mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=###` shouldn't be in the URL, but the link still redirects to the correct page.

I would like to know how I can use **mod_rewrite** in **.htaccess** so that when someone clicks a URL containing `mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=###&`, it automatically reverts to the version not containing it:

Clicking:

> http://
>   mywebsite.com/index.php​?mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=6gqvo88l​u5fnl1qmj7temt0113&topic=316196​.msg931242

Becomes:

> http:// mywebsite.com/index.php​?topic=316196​.msg931242

Comment: Sounds like you've got a bigger issue there. I take it you're using a forum package and your database username is mywebsite_smf. There's no real reason that the forum package should be making these kinds of links - session tokens should ideally be done in cookies. Have a look at the configuration files, or upgrade the system if possible! Looks vulnerable to all sorts of attacks.

Comment: I agree. I know where the issue lies, but I need a quick fix to stop the bleeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [NE,L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava,

But I am getting a 404 error.

    http://mywebsite.com/index.php​?**mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=5lj4j3fi​5g2mc2sa5r9jtb5645&**action=galle​ry 
 
is not becoming
 
http://mywebsite.com/index.php​?action=galle​ry

Comment: Yea, it's not working, unfortunately. I added it to the .htaccess like you said, and when I do visit the website containing the smf1_session, it redirects to a 404 error, page not found. What about the (dot)com part?

Comment: Check your URL as it might have some non-printable characters. This rules works fine on my Apache with `/index.php?mywebsite_smf_smf1_session=5lj4j3fi%E2%80%8B5g2m‌​c2sa5r9%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bjtb5645&action=gallery` and removes first query parameter.